# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (PDO) (Only in one php file)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello guys I got in to problem. I know this question have been answered earlier, but I still can't get trought it. Anything with my database are correct, becouse other php files works fine. Tried another hosting, still same problem.

Core php(Where error occurs):

```
<?php
include('getSecondDropDown.php');

$arrayForSecondDropdown[] = functionName();
foreach($arrayForSecondDropdown as $v){
       echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";
}
?>
```

getSecondDropDown.php:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    function functionName(){
    $Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
    $option="";
              try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='".$Region_ID."'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 

    echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

}
              }
              catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    }
        echo $option;

  ?>
```

Full error code(Shown in web console - sources) :

```
Country: <select name="Country_ID" id="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory<option value=''></option></select></br>
```

Comment: Should be `foreach ($result as $v)`

Comment: You asked this question already. And got your answer. There is nothing else that we can do for you.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes what if you double check your assumption?

Comment: I don't know much about PDO but coming from a mysqli background I believe the iterated array should be $result

Comment: @PhiterFernandes well, you are wrong. Besides, did you read the error message by chance? Does it have anything to do with iteration or results?

Comment: "Anything with my database are correct" - it is not. Make your catch to echo the $servername and $dbname and see

Comment: @YourCommonSense Here isn't full core code. Some lines before these, are querry who takes info from database(regions) and it works.

Comment: it is not about your query. It is not about the code either. The error is because **wrong database credentials.**